# R Aggregate mean

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe with three vectors:

```
location size  sales
A          1    100
A          1    300
A          2    200
A          3    300
B          1    300
B          1    500
C          1    800
C          1    900
B          3    500
B          3    600
```

I want to output a matrix with location on the X axis, size on the Y axis and mean sales of each (location, size) coordinate in the cells (sorted ascending on each axis).

```
   A   B    C
1 200 400   850
2 200     
3 300 550
...
```

I am new to R. 
I think I need to use the aggregate function.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), size~location, value.var="sales", mean)
```